# Pushwoosh.getInstance() error

Tags: android, pushwoosh

I am getting an error when I try to update my pushwoosh applications in the Pushwoosh library.I've updated it in Gradle.

```
07-06 18:21:59.637 19950-19950/com.ahmet.sen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.ahmet.sen, PID: 19950
                                                              java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                  at com.ahmet.sen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.pushwoosh.notification.j com.pushwoosh.c.d()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at com.pushwoosh.Pushwoosh.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.pushwoosh.Pushwoosh.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.ahmet.sen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50) 
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Where i get the error

```
        Pushwoosh.getInstance().registerForPushNotifications();
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating response from [Pushwoosh Github](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-android-sdk/issues/57#issuecomment-317662470) here:

This is not a bug of Pushwoosh SDK. This is a peculiarity of multi-processor applications in Android apps environment.

When you integrate analytics tools such as LeakCanary, AppMetrica, and others, these libraries start a new process for itself. A new instance of the app is created In this process. But you do not need to listen for pushes in this separate process, so by default you should not call `registerForPushNotifications()` inside `Application.onCreate()`.

Therefore there are 2 possible solutions:

- Not to call `registerForPushNotifications` inside `Application.onCreate()`
- If you want to call registerForPushNotifications inside Application.onCreate(), you should perform a check in application's main process:

`List < ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo > runningAppProcesses = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (runningAppProcesses != null && runningAppProcesses.size() != 0) {
     for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo: runningAppProcesses) {
      boolean isCurrentProcess = runningAppProcessInfo.pid == android.os.Process.myPid();
      boolean isMainProcessName = getPackageName().equals(runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
      if (isCurrentProcess && isMainProcessName) {
       Pushwoosh.getInstance().registerForPushNotifications(...);
       break;
      }
     }
    }`